# Two adults staying in a room that says "one adult" on the reservation

Tags: usa, hotels

I am traveling for work.  My company sent me my hotel reservation.  It says "one adult" on it.  I am bringing my wife.  Do I need to sneak her into the room, or will I be fine?

Comment: How would we know? This will depend on the policy of the hotel in question. Ask the person in your company who booked it, or check with the hotel direct.

Comment: @CannonFodder - I presume there is an industry norm.  I'm looking for "likely"

Comment: I think your only problem is if there is a single twin bed. That's very unlikely in a hotel oriented towards businessmen, but it's just _barely_ possible in New York City, maybe a few other places with older hotels. Since there is almost always either two twins (or larger) or one queen, the hotel has no additional expenses for the second person. This is not true for 3 or more.

Comment: @horsehair Given that you'll likely be going to a business-oriented hotel you'll likely be fine. That won't be much help if you arrive at your hotel and you're not actually fine. See my previous comment.

Comment: The tone of you're question suggest you're going to break the rules if the answer will be 'no'...

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g - so?

Comment: I don't think that a wife counts as a guest or friend. Or does she?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a normal, business-oriented hotel in the US with rooms intended for double occupancy, this is not usually a problem.

However, we don't know which hotel you're staying at or their policy, so the best thing to do would be to call the front desk and check. It's possible that there could be a difference in cost, such as if breakfast is included in the room rate, and they'd be able to give you that information in advance so you aren't surprised.

Comment: Or, if the OP really is booked into a room that is only suitable for one person, it may be possible to get an upgrade and pay the difference.